# Regex Replace Zero In Some Instances

Tags: regex, string, replace

I am trying to write a regex statement that will replace all 0 if the following conditions are true

Example string:

```
0,10,9A,0,0,20,0LD,0
```

Change all zeros to a `T0`

- If the 0 has a 1-9 in front do not change it
- If the first character or last character is a 0 change it to a T0
- If the zero has letters after the zero change it to T0 same letters after it as before

The string above can be in any order and should account for a possible change in delims (,)

So the string above should be:

```
T0,10,9A,T0,T0,20,T0LD,T0
```

This is what I have so far:

```
0(?=[A-Z]|[1-9])|0
```

This is what I get

```
T0,1T0,9A,T0,T0,2T0,T0LD,T0
```

The problem is the 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90 are being replaced they should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Negative Lookbehind to do this.

```
(?<![1-9])0
```

Or going off of your current pattern.

```
(?<![1-9])0(?=[A-Z1-9]?)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cM7vM8/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try negative lookbehind assertion

```
"(?<![1-9])0"
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html